# Подключение скриптов в Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

День добрый. При настройке вебпака столкнулся с проблемой, мои скрипты автоматически подключаются в , а не перед закрывающимся тегом . Для подключения скриптов использую html webpack plugin.
Конфиг вебпака:

```
const path = require('path')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './index.js',
        analytics: './analytics.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html"
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader','css-loader']
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Вот что на выходе получается:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
<script defer src="main.f42c425d5bfc7b7676e1.js"></script><script defer src="analytics.82ddc5c3baf1c3a68da9.js"></script></head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. После template нужно указать inject со значением "body".